# cakebake not working with prefix in cakephp3

Tags: caph-framework

I am using cakephp 3.4.9. When I am using a table with prefix n field its working properly after baking but if I use prefix in table fields its not working.

Like when I am using post with following fields like 
id,
post,
date

it's working fine but if I use following fields its not working
p_id,
p_post,
p_date

it is adding extra codes in model

```
$this->belongsTo('Ps', [
         'foreignKey' => 'p_id',
         'joinType' => 'INNER'
     ]);
public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
 {
    $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['p_id'], 'Ps'));

     return $rules;
}
```

why ps is adding here? If I use articales table like same its become As.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to suggest you, read this article.
[CakePHP naming convention documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html)

In cakePHP framework everything you have to keep in mind while creating the table is the CakePHP naming conventions. In your case, This is happening because cakePHP expects the primary column of any table will be only '**id**', and the foreign key for the table will be the *Related table name with an underscore id*
**(ex: If product table BelogsTO categories you have to make a column in your product table as category_id)**

In your case cakePHP considering p_id as a foreign key for the table **P**. And by default cakePHP has a validation for the forein key that the existsIn which means that while saving that p_id, it will check for the existance of id in P table.

In one sentense this is because of the naming convention issue. You can change only p_id to id and keeping other things same will work for you.

HAPPY CODING :)